# Proper use of lightning:select's value attribute and child options' selected attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have some lightning:select code that looks like this:

```
<lightning:select onchange="{!c.onStatusChange}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.statusOptions}" var="option">
        <option text="{!option}" label="{!option}" value="{!option}" selected="{!option.selected}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Starting Summer18 we noticed that *sometimes* the first element is selected even though we'd expect some other element to be selected (based on the `selected` attribute of the child options).

Looking through the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm) I noticed that the `lightning:select` element has a `value` property defined like so:

> The value of the select, also used as the default value to select the right option during init. If no value is provided, the first option will be selected.

This doesn't mention the `option` element's `selected` attribute at all, implying I guess that this is ignored?

And sure enough, setting the `value` attribute on the `lightning:select` seemed to fix things:

```
<lightning:select onchange="{!c.onStatusChange}" value="{!v.selectedOption}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.statusOptions}" var="option">
        <option text="{!option}" label="{!option}" value="{!option}" selected="{!option.selected}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

But this has me questioning the purpose of using the `selected` attribute on the `option` element at all! I noticed though that the code in the documentation has both the `value` attribute set on the `lightning:select` element and also the `selected` attribute set on the `option` element:

here's the example code provided in the above documentation link under the heading *Generating Options On Initialization*:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String" default="Red"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadOptions}" />
    <lightning:select name="mySelect" label="Select a color:" aura:id="mySelect" value="{!v.selectedValue}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
            <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
         </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
</aura:component>
```

My question is, what is the purpose of using both the `value` attribute on the `lightning:select` element *and* the `selected` attribute on `option`? Should I not expect the `selected` attribute to take precedence?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also noticed this problem and I figured out that using `lightning:select` is not the best way to display a combo box because of the `aura:iteration`.

There is a `lightning:combobox` component that is more convenient because its syntax is shorter and it does not have this bug:

```
<aura:attribute name="status" type="String" default="new"/>
<aura:attribute name="statusOptions" type="List" default="[
    {'label': 'New', 'value': 'new'},
    {'label': 'In Progress', 'value': 'inProgress'},
    {'label': 'Finished', 'value': 'finished'},
    ]"/>

<lightning:combobox name="progress" label="Status" value="{!v.status}" placeholder="Select Progress" options="{!v.statusOptions}"/>
```

Documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:combobox/example

Comment: i don't love the answer of _just use something else_. but considering the docs are so poor i'm willing to accept your answer as the unofficial documentation stating _deprecated, use combobox_ :-/